# Magento 2.4.3 create custom pdf

Tags: magento2, phtml, pdf, invoice-pdf

Hi team i have custom data in table formate like below formate

```
<tbody><tr>
                                <td class='item-info'>BT40CC25120ARRIS<br/></td>
                                <td class='item-info'>BT40CC25120</td>
                                <td class='item-qty'>1</td>
                                <td class='item-price'><span class="price">₹1,432.20</span></td>
                             </tr></tbody><tfoot class='order-totals'>
                                <tr class='subtotal'>
                                    <th colspan='3'>Shipping & Handling Charges</th>
                                    <td colspan='3'><span><span class="price">₹0.00</span></span></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class='subtotal'>
                                    <th colspan='3'>Discount</th>
                                    <td colspan='3'><span> -<span class="price">₹0.00</span></span></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class='subtotal'>
                                    <th colspan='3'>Tax Amount</th>
                                    <td colspan='3'><span><span class="price">₹257.80</span></span></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class='subtotal'>
                                    <th colspan='3'>Grandtotal</th>
                                    <td colspan='3'><span><span class="price">₹1,690.00</span></span></td>
                                </tr></tfoot>
```

same I want insert in pdf how can we insert in to pdf

below one I did all ok only total part

```
public function createPdf($emailTemplateVariables) {

        $order = $this->getOrderByIncrementId($emailTemplateVariables['myvar1']);
        $address = $this->addressRenderer->format($order->getBillingAddress(), 'pdf');
        $billingAddress = $this->_invoicepdf->formatAddress($this->addressRenderer->format($order->getBillingAddress(), 'pdf'), $order);
        if (!$order->getIsVirtual()) {
            $shippingAddress = $this->_invoicepdf->formatAddress($this->addressRenderer->format($order->getShippingAddress(), 'pdf'), $order);
            $shippingMethod = $order->getShippingDescription();
        }

        $writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/createPdf.log');
        $logger = new \Zend_Log();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('text message');
        $logger->info('Array Log address' . print_r($address, true));
        $logger->info('Array Log billing' . print_r($billingAddress, true));
        $pdf = new \Zend_Pdf(); //Create new PDF file
        $page = $pdf->newPage(\Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
        $pdf->pages[] = $page;
        $style = new \Zend_Pdf_Style();
        $style->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0, 0, 0));
        $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(\Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA);
        $style->setFont($font, 10);
        $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
        $width = $page->getWidth();
        $hight = $page->getHeight();
        $x = 30;
//      $pageTopalign = 815;
        $this->getLogo($page);
        $this->y = 815 - 100;

//        $style->setFont($font, 15);
        $page->setStyle($style);

        $top = $this->y;

        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.45));
        $page->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.45));
        $page->drawRectangle(25, $top, 570, $top - 55);
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(1));
//        $page->drawRectangle(30, $this->y + 10, $page->getWidth() - 30, $this->y + 70, \Zend_Pdf_Page::SHAPE_DRAW_STROKE);
        $page->drawText(__('Order # ') . $emailTemplateVariables['myvar1'], 30, $top -= 15, 'UTF-8');
        $page->drawText(__('Placed On # ') . $emailTemplateVariables['myvar2'], 30, $top -= 25, 'UTF-8');

        $top -= 30;

        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
        $page->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.5));
        $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
        $page->drawRectangle(25, $top, 275, $top - 25);
        $page->drawRectangle(275, $top, 570, $top - 25);

        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
//        $style->setFont($font, 12);
//        $page->setStyle($style);
        $this->_setFontBold($page, 12);
        $page->drawText(__('Sold to:'), 35, $top - 15, 'UTF-8');
        $page->drawText(__('Ship to:'), 285, $top - 15, 'UTF-8');

        $addressesHeight = $this->_invoicepdf->calcAddressHeight($billingAddress);
        if (isset($shippingAddress)) {
            $addressesHeight = max($addressesHeight, $this->_invoicepdf->calcAddressHeight($shippingAddress));
        }

        $paymentInfo = $this->_paymentData->getInfoBlock($order->getPayment())->setIsSecureMode(true)->toPdf();
        $paymentInfo = htmlspecialchars_decode($paymentInfo, ENT_QUOTES);
        $payment = explode('{{pdf_row_separator}}', $paymentInfo);
        foreach ($payment as $key => $value) {
            if (strip_tags(trim($value)) == '') {
                unset($payment[$key]);
            }
        }
        reset($payment);

        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(1));
        $page->drawRectangle(25, $top - 25, 570, $top - 33 - $addressesHeight);
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
        $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
        $this->y = $top - 40;
        $addressesStartY = $this->y;

//        $billingaddresses = $this->_invoicepdf->addbillingaddresspopdf($billingAddress, $this->y, $page);
//        $this->y = $addressesStartY;
//        $shippingaddresses = $this->_invoicepdf->addshippingaddresspopdf($shippingAddress, $this->y, $page);
//
//        $addressesEndY = min($addressesEndY, $this->y);
//        $this->y = $addressesEndY;

        foreach ($billingAddress as $value) {
            if ($value !== '') {
                $text = [];
                foreach ($this->string->split($value, 45, true, true) as $_value) {
                    $text[] = $this->rtlTextHandler->reverseRtlText($_value);
                }
                foreach ($text as $part) {
                    $page->drawText(strip_tags(ltrim($part)), 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
                    $this->y -= 15;
                }
            }
        }


        $addressesEndY = $this->y;
        if (!$order->getIsVirtual()) {
            $this->y = $addressesStartY;
            foreach ($shippingAddress as $value) {
                if ($value !== '') {
                    $text = [];
                    foreach ($this->string->split($value, 45, true, true) as $_value) {
                        $text[] = $this->rtlTextHandler->reverseRtlText($_value);
                    }
                    foreach ($text as $part) {
                        $page->drawText(strip_tags(ltrim($part)), 285, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
                        $this->y -= 15;
                    }
                }
            }

            $addressesEndY = min($addressesEndY, $this->y);
            $this->y = $addressesEndY;



            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
            $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
            $page->drawRectangle(25, $this->y, 275, $this->y - 25);
            $page->drawRectangle(275, $this->y, 570, $this->y - 25);

            $this->y -= 15;
            $this->_setFontBold($page, 12);
            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
            $page->drawText(__('Payment Method:'), 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
            $page->drawText(__('Shipping Method:'), 285, $this->y, 'UTF-8');

            $this->y -= 10;

            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(1));

            $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));

            $paymentLeft = 35;
            $yPayments = $this->y - 15;
        } else {
            $yPayments = $addressesStartY;
            $paymentLeft = 285;
        }
        foreach ($payment as $value) {
            if (trim($value) != '') {
                //Printing "Payment Method" lines
                $value = preg_replace('/<br[^>]*>/i', "\n", $value);
                foreach ($this->string->split($value, 45, true, true) as $_value) {
                    $page->drawText(strip_tags(trim($_value)), $paymentLeft, $yPayments, 'UTF-8');
                    $yPayments -= 15;
                }
            }
        }
        if ($order->getIsVirtual()) {
            // replacement of Shipments-Payments rectangle block
            $yPayments = min($addressesEndY, $yPayments);
            $page->drawLine(25, $top - 25, 25, $yPayments);
            $page->drawLine(570, $top - 25, 570, $yPayments);
            $page->drawLine(25, $yPayments, 570, $yPayments);

            $this->y = $yPayments - 15;
        } else {
            $topMargin = 15;
            $methodStartY = $this->y;
            $this->y -= 15;
             foreach ($this->string->split($shippingMethod, 45, true, true) as $_value) {
                $page->drawText(strip_tags(trim($_value)), 285, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
                $this->y -= 15;
            }
            $yShipments = $this->y;
            $totalShippingChargesText = "("
                . __('Total Shipping Charges')
                . " "
                . $order->formatPriceTxt($order->getShippingAmount())
                . ")";

            $page->drawText($totalShippingChargesText, 285, $yShipments - $topMargin, 'UTF-8');
            $yShipments -= $topMargin + 10;
             $currentY = min($yPayments, $yShipments);

            // replacement of Shipments-Payments rectangle block
            $page->drawLine(25, $methodStartY, 25, $currentY);
            //left
            $page->drawLine(25, $currentY, 570, $currentY);
            //bottom
            $page->drawLine(570, $currentY, 570, $methodStartY);
            //right

            $this->y = $currentY;
            $this->y -= 15;
        }
        
//         $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
//            $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
//            $page->drawRectangle(25, $this->y, 275, $this->y - 25);
//            $page->drawRectangle(275, $this->y, 570, $this->y - 25);
//
//            $this->y -= 15;
//            $this->_setFontBold($page, 12);
//            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
//            $page->drawText(__('Payment Method:'), 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
//            $page->drawText(__('Shipping Method:'), 285, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
//
//            $this->y -= 10;

//            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(1));
//
//            $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
//            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
            
            /* Add table */
            $this->_invoicepdf->_drawpoHeader($page, $this->y);
//            $this->y -= 20;
//            $page->drawText(trim(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($emailTemplateVariables['myvar8']))), 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
             /* Add body */
            foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
                if ($item->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }
                /* Draw item */
                
                 $this->_invoicepdf->drawpoItems($item, $page, $order);
                $page = end($pdf->pages);
            }
            $this->y -= 20;
            $this->_invoicepdf->insertpoTotals($page,$order);
//            $page->drawRectangle();
//             $page->drawLine(25, $this->y - 8, $page->getWidth()-30, $this->y + 12);
        $pdfData = $pdf->render(); // Get PDF document as a string

        header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=result.pdf");

        header("Content-type: application/x-pdf");
        return $pdfData;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First add `dompdf` using composer

```
composer require dompdf/dompdf
```

Now add a helper class in your module, like `app/code/Vendor/Module/Helper/HtmltoPdf.php`

Use following code for your helper file:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;

class HtmlToPdf extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $dompdf;
    protected $dompdfOptions;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Dompdf\Dompdf $dompdf,
        \Dompdf\Options $dompdfOptions
    )
    {
        $this->dompdf = $dompdf;
        $this->dompdfOptions = $dompdfOptions;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function setPdfHeaders()
    {
        $this->dompdfOptions->set('isRemoteEnabled', true);
        $this->dompdf->setOptions($this->dompdfOptions);
        $this->dompdf->set_option('isRemoteEnabled', true);
        $this->dompdf->setPaper('A4');
    }

    public function getPageBreakHtml()
    {
        return "<div style='page-break-before: always;'></div>";
    }

    public function setPdfHtml($html)
    {
        $this->dompdf->loadHtml($html);
    }

    public function getOutput($fileName = "")
    {
        if(empty($fileName)){
            $fileName = date("Ymd-His.pdf");
        }
        //Close and output PDF document
        // Render the HTML as PDF
        $this->dompdf->render();

        // Output the generated PDF to Browser
        $this->dompdf->stream($fileName);
    }
}
```

Now in your controller, like `app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Index/Index.php` use following code:

```
protected $htmlToPdf;
protected $resultPageFactory;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Vendor\Module\Helper\HtmlToPdf $htmlToPdf,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    ...
)
{
    ...
    $this->htmlToPdf = $htmlToPdf;
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    ...
}

public function execute()
{
    try {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

        $html = $resultPage->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template')
            ->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::your_html.phtml')
            ->toHtml();

        $this->htmlToPdf->setPdfHeaders();
        $this->htmlToPdf->setPdfHtml($html);
        $this->htmlToPdf->getOutput("output-file-name.pdf");
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: dompdf is ok but i have code not phtml file and already I was done all data display like billing and shipping address display but here items only different for order and vendor prices so

Comment: If you have html code and not phtml, then you can assign your html directoly to `$html` variable instead of calling phtml. Like `$html = "my html in string";`